# Filtering duplicate hashes from array of hashes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes, like this:

```
[{id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735", name: "italy"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c6941735", name: "skandi"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d147941735", name: "diner"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735", name: "italy"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d14a941735", name: "vietnam"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1ce941735", name: "fish"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"}]
```

I want to throw out duplicate hashes. Set doesn't work because hashes are unique objects.

I feel stuck and need a kick to think. Please advise!

Comment: Reduce the array to an object, using the id as key, and then convert back to array using `Object.values()`.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: You would have to loop through the array for each possible hash and check, remove. Or change the data format, use an object with the hash string as a key and the name and whatever else as a separate object for the value

Comment: Only pure JS allowed?

Comment: @hindmost, yes, this is part of my react app

Comment: You can't use any library with react? such as lodash?

Comment: No, not allowed

Comment: @ZiTAL he says he tried set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) too

```js
//I added comma to each object
const data= [{id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735", name: "italy"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c6941735", name: "skandi"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d147941735", name: "diner"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735", name: "italy"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d14a941735", name: "vietnam"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1ce941735", name: "fish"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"},
    {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"}]

const result= data.reduce((current,next)=>{   
    if(!current.some(a=> a.name === next.name)){
        current.push(next);
    }
    return current;
},[])
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
h.filter(( t={}, a=>!(t[a.id]=a.id in t) ))
```

Input array in h, time complexity *O(n)*,  explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453045/860099)[.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/9L0mwgjt/12/)

```js
let h = [{id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735", name: "italy"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c6941735", name: "skandi"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d147941735", name: "diner"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735", name: "italy"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d14a941735", name: "vietnam"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1ce941735", name: "fish"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"},
 {id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735", name: "resto"}]
 
 let t; // declare t to avoid use global (however works without it too)
 let r= h.filter(( t={}, a=>!(t[a.id]=a.id in t) ))

 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Answer (score 4):

Space for time

```js
let arr = [
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d110941735', name: 'italy' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d1c6941735', name: 'skandi' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d147941735', name: 'diner' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d110941735', name: 'italy' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735', name: 'resto' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d14a941735', name: 'vietnam' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d1ce941735', name: 'fish' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735', name: 'resto' },
    { id: '4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735', name: 'resto' }
]

let map = {};
let rest = arr.filter((item) => {
    if(map[item.id] === void 0) {
        map[item.id] = item.id;
        return true;
    }
});
map = null;

console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an approach with associative arrays, this makes duplicate removal easier. If you can, you should build your array as an associative array in the first place, so that you don't have to convert it. Here is how you do it:

```js
var array = [{
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735",
    name: "italy"
  },
  {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c6941735",
    name: "skandi"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d147941735",
    name: "diner"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735",
    name: "italy"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735",
    name: "resto"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d14a941735",
    name: "vietnam"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d14a941735",
    name: "fish"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735",
    name: "resto"
  }, {
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735",
    name: "resto"
  }
];

// you can access the array with arrayAssociative[id], where the id is the real id like "4bf58dd8d48988d110941735"
var arrayAssociative = {};
for (item in array) {
  // first get the unique id's
  var addedNode = arrayAssociative[array[item].id] = arrayAssociative[array[item].id] || {};
  if (addedNode.names == null)
    addedNode.names = {};
  // now get the unique names
  var addedName = arrayAssociative[array[item].id].names[array[item].name] = arrayAssociative[array[item].id].names[array[item].name] || {};
}
console.log(arrayAssociative);
```

I don't know the exact reason, why the line

> var element = arrayAssociative[id] =arrayAssociative[id] || {};

works for this, but let's just accept the funcitonality as it is :)

Comment: `arrayAssociative[array[item].id] || {}` this line gives value in left of `||` if it is not null/undefined/0/false or value in the right if opposit - https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100758/860099