# Find if arrays repeat and then select them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have multiple arrays in a main/parent array like this:

```
var arr = [
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [2, 12],
    [5, 9],
    [2, 12],
    [6, 2],
    [2, 12],
    [2, 12]
];
```

I have the code to select the arrays that are repeated 3 or more times (> 3) and assign it to a variable.

The code is:

```js
var arr = [[1, 17], [1, 17], [1, 17], [2, 12], [5, 9], [2, 12], [6, 2], [2, 12]]
arr.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1])

// define equal for array
const equal = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.every((n, j) => n === arr2[j])

let GROUP_SIZE = 3
first = 0, last = 1, res = []

while(last < arr.length){
    if (equal(arr[first], arr[last])) last++
    else {
        if (last - first >= GROUP_SIZE)  res.push(arr[first])
        first = last
    }
}
if (last - first >= GROUP_SIZE)  res.push(arr[first])
console.log(res)
```

So the final result is:

```
console.log(repeatedArrays);
>>> [[1, 17], [2, 12]]
```

---

**My problem:** But the problem is, I have an array like this `{from: [12, 0], to: [14, 30]}`.

```
var arr = [
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [2, 12],
    [5, 9],
    [2, 12],
    [6, 2],
    {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]},
    {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]},
    {from: [4, 30], to: [8, 20]},
    {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]},
    {from: [4, 30], to: [8, 20]},
    [2, 12],
    [2, 12]
];
```

When I try to use the above code, it doesn't work. The error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: arr1.every is not a function

The final result **should** be:

```
console.log(repeatedArrays);
>>> [[1, 17], [2, 12], {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]}]
```

How can I make that code above work?

Comment: What sort of logic are you looking for? Would you need to find 3 duplicates of the full `{ from, to }` object for it to be included in the final result, or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784726/find-duplicate-array-within-array

Comment: You need to pass in an array. `{from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]}` is an object.

Comment: *"...I have an array like this `{from: [12, 0], to: [14, 30]}`"* How is that object equivalent to: `var array = [
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [2, 12],
    [5, 9],
    [2, 12],
    [6, 2],
    {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]},
    [2, 12],
    [2, 12]
];` ? And why is this object: `{from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]}` stuffed in an array of arrays so haphazardly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you introduce a non array into the mix, you need to handle it differently.

Yours already work with array so I'm adding object style check for both sort and equal.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 17],
  [1, 17],
  [1, 17],
  [2, 12],
  [5, 9],
  [2, 12],
  [6, 2],
  { from: [4, 30], to: [8, 21] },
  { from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5] },
  { from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5] },
  { from: [4, 30], to: [8, 20] },
  { from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5] },
  { from: [4, 30], to: [8, 20] },
  [2, 12],
  [2, 12]
];
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a instanceof Array && b instanceof Array) {
    return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]
  } else if (a instanceof Array || b instanceof Array) {
    return a instanceof Array ? -1 : 1
  } else {
    return a.from[0] - b.from[0] || a.from[1] - b.from[1] || a.to[0] - b.to[0] || a.to[1] - b.to[1]
  }
});

// define equal for array
const equal = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1 instanceof Array) {
    return arr1.every((n, j) => n === arr2[j]);
  } else {
    if (arr2 instanceof Array) return false;
    for (let k in arr1) {
      if (!arr1[k].every((n, j) => n === arr2[k][j])) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
};

let GROUP_SIZE = 3;
(first = 0), (last = 1), (res = []);

while (last < arr.length) {
  if (equal(arr[first], arr[last])) last++;
  else {
    if (last - first >= GROUP_SIZE) res.push(arr[first]);
    first = last;
  }
}
if (last - first >= GROUP_SIZE) res.push(arr[first]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I want it to output `[[1, 17], [2, 12], {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]}]`

Comment: @baileyJchoi I've edited the answer. It surprisingly doesn't work well on Safari & Firefox. It works in Node.js & Chrome though. Hmm...

Comment: Hmm do you know why though?

Comment: It seems like `[2, 12]` is not being added in. I wonder why it's skipping it...

Comment: @baileyJchoi Updated it again. It should work on Safari and Firefox too now.

Comment: But, FF and Safari require the array to be sorted first? Weird...

Comment: @baileyJchoi Both needed the array to be sorted just that the implementation did not sort the array properly on Safari and Firefox. It works now on them too now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and counting the objects and then execute the function `filter` for getting the object with count `>= 3`.

```js
var array = [     [1, 17],     [1, 17],     [1, 17],     [2, 12],     [5, 9],     [2, 12],     [6, 2],     [2, 12],     [2, 12] ];

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, [c, b]) => {
  let key = `${c}|${b}`;
  (a[key] || (a[key] = {count: 0, value: [c, b]})).count++;
  return a;
}, {})).filter(o => {
  if (o.count >= 3) {
    delete o.count;
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}).map(({value}) => value);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: I want it to output `[[1, 17], [2, 12], {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]}]`

Answer (score 0):

Really simple - `filter` it all, then remove duplicates with `Set` and JSON methods (because it's nested arrays not objects):

```js
var array = [
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [1, 17],
    [2, 12],
    [5, 9],
    [2, 12],
    [6, 2],
    [2, 12],
    [2, 12]
];

var repeatedArrays = [...new Set(array.filter(e => array.filter(f => JSON.stringify(e.sort()) == JSON.stringify(f.sort()))).map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);

console.log(repeatedArrays);
```

Comment: I want it to output `[[1, 17], [2, 12], {from: [12, 0], to: [14, 5]}]`